# Trying to use Ballerina extension -Error: DeprecateWarning:Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues -

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, runtime-error, ballerina, ballerina-vscode-plugin

[Error on checking the Visual studio log]

I am not able to use the properties and methods of the library, the extension is not working properly, I have tried everything but nothing is working. Can somebody tell me where I need to change & what I need to change exactly?

Comment: can you open the "view->output" and select "Ballerina" from the dropdown available in the top right of the output view you might be able to see any logs and you will be able to see whether correct Ballerina distribution has been picked up by the extension... also what Ballerina version you currently using ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to user settings in VSCode and search for Ballerina. There are two checkboxes to enable trace logs and the debug logs. Enable them and go to the output panel and then select Ballerina there. You will see the error logs there, and check whether the correct plugin version and ballerina installation is picked. If possible, share the log as well